# How to define endpoint without web.config or httpModule?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I would like to make a RESTful app of HTTPhandlers without having to define every endpoint by making an entry in the web.config, i'd like the style of attaching attributes to a class constructor eg:

```
public class obj : IHttpHandler
{
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/accounts/{id}")]
  public obj(string id)
  {
     // this is just an eg, it worild normally include caching and 
     // a template system
     String html = File.ReadAllText("/accounts/accounts.htm");
     html.replace("id", id);
     httpcontext.current.response.write(html)
  }
}
```

instead of

```
<httpHandlers>
      <clear />
      <add verb="GET" path="/accounts/*" type="MyApp.obj" />
</httphandlers>
```

The way i'm doing it now i have 100's of endpoints in the web.config :( i'd rather define them in the class. And i don't want to make extra files (.asmx) either. I'd like an app of just .htm files with tokens and .cs files

Thanks!

Comment: consider revising the code snippet: "public call obj"? "public obj(string id)"?

Comment: I am considering revisin the question the be : Which method is is responsible for parsing the request URL and choosing which httphandler to instantiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could automate the registration of the endpoints and so on, with a custom ServiceHost, which overrides the ApplyConfiguration() method, which then virtualizes the configuration so that it does not have to be in the web.config file.

[Here's a starting point](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/22/custom-service-config-file-for-a-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx).  It doesn't do exactly what you want, but it illustrates the concept of virtualizing the configuration.

Comment: This looks like the way to go, ServiceHostBase.AddServiceEndpoint Method (String, Binding, Uri) Thank you!